# Additional textbox for adding unique css classes to images uploaded

Tags: entities, paragraphs

My project has a custom module that uses the paragraphs module. I have a background image upload field that now requires an additional textbox field to set unique css classes for the individual images uploaded.
Everything currently works as expected although I am now seeing that some images, which are used in many different types of layouts, are not very responsive to mobile views. I have set some breakpoints but it also effects the background images that respond very well to mobile. So having an option to set an image class on the individual image uploaded would be ideal.

Any suggestions or solutions would be highly appreciated.
Thanks